# Blocking the main queue

Tags: swift

I want flag to change as 'false' but it stays 'true'. How can I block my main queue ? Could you please explain with code ?

```
var flag = true;
    var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
    var task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!){
        (data,response,error) in
        var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        flag = false
    }
    task.resume()
    println(flag)
```

Comment: A simple solution would be to use a semaphore. However, I guess there's a more smart build-in solution which I don't know :-/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a synchronous request, one that blocks the current thread, you should just use NSURLConnection's [sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:) instead. There is no reason to create a download task if you want to block until it is done.

```
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
var response: NSURLResponse?
var error: NSError?
if let data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error) {
    let urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
else {
    // handle error
}
```

**However, blocking the main thread waiting for a network request is a really bad idea**. The user will certainly notice the freeze in the app and be frustrated. I would strongly advise you to find a way of achieving this without having to block the main thread.